# Getting the average duration from an array of dates using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am trying to get average order duration for a client based on all order dates.

Array have list of order dates like this

```
$all_order_dates = [
'0'=>'2019-01-01',
'1'=>'2019-01-05',
'2'=>'2019-01-25',
'3'=>'2019-02-03',
'4'=>'2019-03-10',
'5'=>'2019-04-20', .... So on..
]
```

How to get the avg order duration in days.

Comment: You forgot to include the question :)

Comment: WHat's the logic or data, clue to get avg order duration in days?

Comment: Does the data come from any DB? If so I'd do it there instead of in php

Comment: @Eddie  last line

Comment: @Rahul Meshram  Yes , avg order duration in days.

Comment: “I want” is not a question. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to show what you already tried, and a _proper_ explanation of what problem you are facing.

Comment: @YogeshSaroya Not a question.

Comment: Can you elaborate `avg order` with some example and update a question with output you are expecting?

Comment: @Rahul Meshram in other word, an array have list of dates, how to get average days based on those dates.

Comment: @B001  Yes (mysql) but i want to do calculation using php array

Comment: _“how to get average days based on those dates”_ - average of _what_? The distance from one entry to the next maybe? I am having a hard time matching the “quality” of your question here with your description on your profile tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
$count = $total = 0;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//PARA: Date Should In YYYY-MM-DD Format
//RESULT FORMAT:
// '%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'        =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Day 11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%y Year %m Month %d Day'                                      =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Days
// '%m Month %d Day'                                              =>  3 Month 14 Day
// '%d Day %h Hours'                                              =>  14 Day 11 Hours
// '%d Day'                                                       =>  14 Days
// '%h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'                                =>  11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%i Minute %s Seconds'                                         =>  49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%h Hours                                                      =>  11 Hours
// '%a Days                                                       =>  468 Days
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function dateDifference($date_1, $date_2, $differenceFormat = '%a')
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}
foreach ($all_order_dates as $key => $val) {
    if ($key < count($all_order_dates) - 1) {
        $diff = dateDifference(($all_order_dates[$key]), ($all_order_dates[$key + 1]));
        $total += $diff;
        $count++;
    }

}
echo "Average order days is", $total / $count;
```

[Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php#115065) for reference function.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/92cf03b2cd55f388da1f6abfe7451c8b05bd9b91).